# Python - Multiple arguments with space

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Want to make a function that needs 2 required arguments with spaces (Arg 1 = A B C, Arg 2 = D E F)
but how can i do that?
i already tried

```py
def foo(*, arg1, *, arg2)
```

but it raised a SyntaxError

Comment: are you trying to do `def foo(*arg1, *arg2)` ?

Comment: You can't invent your own syntax. Unless you're writing your own language.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri No

Comment: @khelwood oh. okay

Comment: What was the problem with `def foo(arg1, arg2)`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it dosent support multiple spaced arguments (a b <- it dosent suport that, rather, it detects only a for arg1 and b for arg2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the syntax of language like this, at least in Python. As far as I saw, idiomatic way of passing more than one sequence of objects is constructing `tuple`s:

```py
>>> def foo(args1, args2):
...     print(args1)
...     print(args2)

    
>>> foo((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
(1, 2, 3)
(4, 5, 6)
>>>
```

Comment: That's actually helpful, Thank you.

Comment: May you accept my post as an answer if it solves your problem?

Comment: Sorry, i got carried away coding xd